# Android Display sonar-report.json in Html or in Dashboard

Tags: android, sonarqube-4.5

I am trying to integrate sonar in my application and before doing that I am trying to see the analysis of running it on a test project which I found on Github. I am able to successful run the analysis through `./gradlew sonarRunner`

And I see that `/sonar-report.json` is being generated. How do I see this report in my dashboard?

The project that I am trying to run the analysis on can be found on this link:

```
https://github.com/sonar-intellij-plugin/android-studio-example-project
```

Answer (score 1):

To view the sonar-report.json you should add the following lines in your sonar-project.properties file:

```
sonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true
sonar.issuesReport.json.enable=true
sonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json
sonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true
sonar.analysis.mode=preview
```

Then it will generate a html with the data of json file.